# Adding changes listeners in Grails' GORM

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-2.0

I'm new to Grails and I'm using Grails 2.0.1. I want to add a persistence event listener for changes in objects for a domain class, so I tried the code in Bootstrap.groovy as given in the user guide:

```
def init = {
    applicationContext.addApplicationListener(new FooBarListener())
}
```

And I get the following error message:

> ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error executing bootstraps: No such property: applicationContext for class: BootStrap

How can I get the ***applicacionContext*** property from inside the BootStrap class?
or Is the documentation outdated and there is a new/better way to add domain changes listeners?.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ApplicationAttributes

class BootStrap {

    def init = {servletContext ->

        def applicationContext = servletContext.getAttribute(ApplicationAttributes.APPLICATION_CONTEXT) 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work but I had another related problem. Now the error message says: `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.grails.datastore.mapping.engine.event.AbstractPersistenceEventListener: method <init>()V not found`. Do you know how to implement a working listener?.

Answer (score 8):

The shortest way I know is

```
class BootStrap {

   def grailsApplication

   def init = { servletContext ->
      def applicationContext = grailsApplication.mainContext
   }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

applicacionContext  must be defined in BootStrap. Following should work

```
     class BootStrap {
       def applicacionContext 

    def init = {
     applicationContext.addApplicationListener(new FooBarListener())
    }

   }
```

Comment: For starters, no it won't work, and besides it's not spelled correctly.

Comment: Sorry about the spelling mistake..thanks for catching it..You are right..I thought since grailsApplication and services are available in Bootstrap, the applicationContext should  be available. But I was wrong..

Comment: Easy enough to test before posting :)